# Lottie animation not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, lottie

I am currently having an issue with my Lottie animation code. What I want to do is to have 2 Lottie animation sets, one on top of another. There will be a second one that is invisible. This will be accomplished via the display property being set to none.

When the first animation set is complete, the second animation set will appear and the first one will disappear. The first set will be controlled by clicking. While the second set is set to trigger when the mouse moves over the animation.

I am about 80% of the way there in terms of working. I have been able to add a second animation and control the display properties. however, I am running into a couple of issues.

1. The first set of animations does not complete. It goes through the first one and then moves to the second set. How do I make it so that the first set does not move too early on the second animation set?

```js
anim = LottieInteractivity.create({
    player:'#chainLoadPlayer',
    mode:"chain",
    actions: [
        {
            state: 'click',
            transition: 'onComplete',
        },
        {
            state: 'click',
            transition: 'onComplete',
            path: 'https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_gijh4f7x.json'
        },
        {
            state: 'click',
            transition: 'none',
            path: 'https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_KGe4XLsK0f.json'
        }
        
    ]
});

anim12 = LottieInteractivity.create({
    player:'#explodingBird12',
    mode:"chain",
    actions: [
        {
            state: 'none',
            transition: 'hold',
            frames: 'bird'
        },
        {
            state: 'autplay',
            transition: 'hold',
            frames: 'explosion'
        },
        {
            state: 'autoplay',
            transition: 'hold',
            frames: 'feathers',
            reset: true
        }
    ]
});

</script>
<script defer>
var animationer = document.querySelector("#chainLoadPlayer")


anim.player.addEventListener("enterFrame", () => {
    //console.log(anim.player.currentFrame)
    if(anim.player.currentFrame >= anim.player.totalFrames - 2)
    {
        anim.player.pause()
        document.querySelector('.animation1').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('.player').style.display = 'block';
    }
});


anim12.player.addEventListener("enterFrame", () => {
    //console.log(anim12.player.currentFrame)
    if(anim12.player.currentFrame >= anim12.player.totalFrames - 2)
    {
        anim12.player.pause()
    }
});


anim12.player.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    anim12.playSegments([1, 10], true);
    anim12.setSubframe(true);
    anim12.goToAndStop(1, true);
    anim12.setSubframe(false);
    anim12.setDirection(1);
    anim12.play();
    anim12.setAction(1, 'autoplay');
});

anim12.player.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    anim12.pause();
    anim12.setDirection(-1);
    anim12.setAction(3, 'none');
    anim12.play();
});
```

```css
.player
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 35px;
    }

    .animation1
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .animation2
    {
        z-index: 3;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>

<lottie-player
  mode="normal"
  id="chainLoadPlayer"
  style="width: 320px"
  src="https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rwxhwdwu.json"
  class="container animation1">
</lottie-player>

<lottie-player
  mode="normal"
  id="explodingBird12"
  style="width: 320px"       
  src="https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_zyquagfl.json"
  class="container animation2 player">
</lottie-player>
```